# SonarCloud does not show tests results

Tags: c#, azure, azure-pipelines, sonarcloud

I have setup SonarCloud with my C# project, and it works fine, I can see `Code Coverage` and `Unit Tests` but these `Unit Tests` are only static number of my tests i.e. `13` when I entered into this I cannot see the tests structure instead `No results`. I checked logs from `SonarCloud Analyze` and it does not contain any errors. All my tests are in `XUnit` and all results are stored in `XUnitResults.xml` file that is provided via `sonar.cs.xunit.reportsPaths=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/**/XUnitResults.xml` - this line consumes all `XUnitResults.xml`.

```
INFO: Sensor C# Tests Coverage Report Import [csharp] (done) | time=699ms
INFO: Sensor C# Unit Test Results Import [csharp]
INFO: Parsing the XUnit Test Results file 'D:\a\1\s\{MY_PROJECT_PATH}\XUnitResults.xml'.
INFO: Parsing the XUnit Test Results file 'D:\a\1\s\{MY_PROJECT_PATH}\XUnitResults.xml'.
INFO: Sensor C# Unit Test Results Import [csharp] (done) | time=41ms
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=1ms
```

Additionally for the coverage I do have a line `sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/**/Coverage.opencover.xml` which is also consumed fine.

```
INFO: Sensor C# [csharp] (done) | time=720ms
INFO: Sensor C# Tests Coverage Report Import [csharp]
INFO: Parsing the OpenCover report D:\a\1\s\TestResults\Coverage.opencover.xml
INFO: Adding this code coverage report to the cache for later reuse: D:\a\1\s\TestResults\Coverage.opencover.xml
```

I tried to use `.trx` and unfortunately it does not work as here, the only result was a static number of tests.

Comment: Could you please share the build definition with us? Are you using the tasks from [Sonar Cloud extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarcloud)?

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT My solution is being build using `dontnetcorecli@2` tasks, and this task is also used to run all tests that produce the `XUnitResults.xml` file. This file is correct, as I checked this command using `dotnet test <args>` with the same args provided in the Azure DevOps and the output is as expected. As for `SonarCloud` I use 3 tasks, `SonarCloudPrepare`, `SonarCloudAnalyze` and `SonarCloudPublish` in the `SonarCloudPrepare` I've extra properties with these lines above.

Comment: And the answer was?

Comment: There was no answer.